# How can I set the switchport's trunk protocol?

Tags: cisco, switch, trunk

How can I set the switchport's trunk protocol?

I saw there can use the command to set the trunk mode:

```
SW(config-if)# switch trunk encapsulation ?
    dot1q
    isl
    negotiate
```

but I tried bellow command did not found the command.

```
Switch(config-if)#switchport mode trunk 
Switch(config-if)#switchport trunk en?
% Unrecognized command
Switch(config-if)#switchport ?
  access         Set access mode characteristics of the interface
  mode           Set trunking mode of the interface
  nonegotiate    Device will not engage in negotiation protocol on this
                 interface
  port-security  Security related command
  priority       Set appliance 802.1p priority
  protected      Configure an interface to be a protected port
  trunk          Set trunking characteristics of the interface
  voice          Voice appliance attributes
Switch(config-if)#switchport trunk ?
  allowed  Set allowed VLAN characteristics when interface is in trunking mode
  native   Set trunking native characteristics when interface is in trunking
           mode
```

I use the Switch 2950T-24 in Cisco Packet Tracer.

Comment: You can't set the trunking protocol on a layer 2 switch. It'll always use Dot1q (IEEE 802.1Q encapsulation) when setting the mode to trunk.

Comment: @Cown: try that on a classic Cat3750G.  It won't even let you set the interface to `mode trunk` before the encapsulation mode isn't fixed.

Comment: @Marc'netztier'Luethi not a layer 2 switch. It has layer 3 capabilities.

Comment: @Cown Care to elaborate on the relationship of ISL-vs-802.1 trunking support and L2/L3 capabilities? The cat2950s certainly didn't have L3 capability, but supported both ISL and 802.1q.

Comment: @Marc'netztier'Luethi the Cisco 2950 never had ISL capabilities. You can check it yourself: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/lan-switching/8021q/24067-195.html

Comment: @Marc'netztier'Luethi *Catalyst 2950/2955 Series Switches: All Ethernet interfaces support 802.1Q. There is no support for ISL encapsulation.*

Comment: @cown that may be correct (2950 not supporting ISL, I humbly stand corrected), but still does not support your argument that the Cat3750's L3 capablity makes any difference in the context of trunking encapsulation. The venerable 3524XL was L2-only, but spoke both ISL and 802.1q.

Comment: @Marc'netztier'Luethi i stand corrected on the 3524XL or 3548XL being layer 2, didn't think that far back sadly, but you are right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only Cisco switch platforms that still support `isl` trunking need to have the trunking protocol configured.

Newer platforms have no support for isl trunking anymore, so the interface command `switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q` is default/implicit/unsupported, and there's no need to configure it. Just set `switchport mode trunk`.

Of the ones that still support isl, Cat3750, 3550, 3560 spring to mind, and the Cat4000 and Cat4500 Series (incl their 4900M and 4948 cousins), and probably a few of the older ones, too.

EDIT: the following section is incorrect as it seems that the 29xx range never had support for isl trunking at all.

---

I couldn't say when ISL trunking support was dropped from the 2950/2960G/2960-S/2960-X product line.

---

Eventually, it's just a matter of trying. If the switchport won't accept `switchport mode trunk`, then setting the trunking encapsulation is probably needed.

Comment: Again, ISL trunking was never supported on any 2950/2960G/2960-S/2960-X product.

Answer (score 0):

In cisco switch 2950 which is layer2 switch trunk port as Configure as fallows

`Switch(config)#intf0/1`

`Switch(config)#switchport mode  trunk`

`Switch(config)#switchport mode trunk allowed vlan all`

`Switch(config)#noshutdown`

Below command is used in catalyst layer3 switch 3750 ,3850

`Switch(config)#int f0/1`

`Switch(config)#Switchport mode trunk`

`Switch(config)#switchport trunk encapsulation dot q`

`Switch(config)#no shutdown`